# what is the maximum video size we can upload to youtube using asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube

Hi i am uploading video to youtube through my asp.net website using the Browser based upload.

```
YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService("MyAppName", devkey);
YouTubeRequestSettings objSettings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("eBizLink", devkey, username, password);
objSettings.Timeout = 999999990;
objSettings.Maximum = 2000000000;
YouTubeRequest objRequest = new YouTubeRequest(objSettings);
((GDataRequestFactory)objRequest.Service.RequestFactory).Timeout = 9999999;
((GDataRequestFactory)service.RequestFactory).KeepAlive = false;
objRequest.Settings.Timeout = 9999999;//60 * 60 * 1000

//objSettings.Timeout = 10000000;
//objSettings.Maximum = 2000000000;
Video objNewVideo = new Video();
//objNewVideo.Title = txtTitle.Text.Trim();
objNewVideo.Title = ViewState["VideoName"].ToString();
objNewVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Animals", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
objNewVideo.Keywords = txtKeyWrd.Text.Trim();
objNewVideo.Description = txtDescription.Text.Trim();
objNewVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
objNewVideo.YouTubeEntry.AccessControls.Add(new YtAccessControl("list", "denied"));

//objNewVideo.YouTubeEntry.State.Name="restricted";
//objNewVideo.YouTubeEntry.State.Reason = "Must login";
objNewVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
objNewVideo.YouTubeEntry.Location = new GeoRssWhere(37, -122);
objNewVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(FilePath, "video/mp4");
Video createdVideo = objRequest.Upload(objNewVideo);
```

Web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="24000" maxRequestLength="4124672" requestValidationMode="4.5"/>
<requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648"/>
</requestFiltering>
```

This is accepting maximum 100MB but i want 2GB videos to be uploaded.

My Queries:
Do i need to do some changes to the above code
OR
Do i need to do some changes to the account settings.

Answer (score 0):

> File size is limited to 2 GB for uploads from the YouTube web page, or 20 GB if up-to-date browser versions are used

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YouTube#Uploading

Answer (score 0):

try this

```xml
<system.webServer>
   <security>
     <requestFiltering>
       <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824"/>
     </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will work for 1GB. Increase  maxAllowedContentLength at will.

Comment: Hi Melkor!!  I have tried this but it is not even uploading 350MB video.